# Unable to access elements parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following a [tutorial](http://brilliantbritz.com/2015/06/17/creating-your-own-angular-material-right-navigation-menu/) to implement a drop down menu with AngularJS's `sidenav`. I have used components in my application so my layout differs from the example provided.

The `ul` is populated with the names stored in an object, but the functions are failing. I am narrowed it down to work out the error is due to not being able to find the directives parent elements controller.

```
var controller = $element.parent().controller();
```

When I log `controller` in the console, it should display the controllers functions which are:

```
vm.isOpen = isOpen;
vm.toggleOpen = toggleOpen;
vm.autoFocusContent = false;
vm.menu = mainNavService;
vm.status = {
    isFirstOpen: true,
    isFirstDisabled: false
};
```

But instead it returns and empty object. Is it because rather than use a controller, I am using Angular's component method on the module and using the controller property?

***Question***

Why when trying to access the controller, it returns no properties?

```
app.component('mainnav', {
    templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/app/views/main-nav.htm',
    controller: ['userService', 'mainNavService', function(userService, mainNavService){

        var vm = this;

        vm.isOpen = isOpen;
        vm.toggleOpen = toggleOpen;
        vm.autoFocusContent = false;
        vm.menu = mainNavService;
        vm.status = {
          isFirstOpen: true,
          isFirstDisabled: false
        };
        function isOpen(section) {
            console.log('menu.isSectionSelected(section)')
          return menu.isSectionSelected(section);
        }
        function toggleOpen(section) {
                console.log(menu.toggleSelectSection(section))
          menu.toggleSelectSection(section);
        }
    }]
})

app.directive('menuToggle', [ '$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
        scope: {
            section: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/app/views/main-nav-li.htm',
        link: function($scope, $element) {

            var controller = $element.parent().controller(); //FAILS

            $scope.isOpen = function() {
                return controller.isOpen($scope.section)
            };
            $scope.toggle = function() {
                console.log(controller.toggleOpen())
                controller.toggleOpen($scope.section);
            };
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: Did you try declaring `mainnav` as a directive instead of a component?

Comment: Why not pass in a reference to your `mainnav` to `menuToggle` like `scope:
 {section: '=', context: '='}`

And in your `main-nav.htm` do `<menu-toggle section="blah" context="$ctrl"></menu-toggle>`

Comment: In general with components, the accepted way of accessing parent controllers is to use the `require` property. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Intercomponent Communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)

Comment: Thank you all. @AdityaParab your solution worked. Thank you. Write it as an answer and I will happily accept!

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott: Very generous of you. Added answer. I have some recommendations for you as well.. Will add it in the `EDIT` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A javascript context can be passed around pretty easily. What you can do is, in change your `menuToggle` directive like

```
app.directive('menuToggle', [ '$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
        scope: {
            section: '=',
            context: '=' // NOTE: This is what the parent component will pass
        },
        templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/app/views/main-nav-li.htm',
        link: function($scope, $element) {
            var controller = $scope.context; // This is reference to parent
            $scope.isOpen = function() {
                return controller.isOpen($scope.section)
            };
            $scope.toggle = function() {
                console.log(controller.toggleOpen())
                controller.toggleOpen($scope.section);
            };
        }
    };
}])
```

And Inside your `main-nav.htm` you need to do

`<menu-toggle section="blah" context="$ctrl"></menu-toggle>`

EDIT::

The functions `$scope.isOpen` and `$scope.toggle` are also unnecessary. (unless you have some specific requirement to have them the way you have now)

In your `main-nav-li.htm` Wherever you find `isOpen()` replace that with `context.isOpen(section)` and wherever you have `toggle()`, Replace that with `context.toggle(section)`

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in jsfiddle and this is what I changed:

First I changed the component to a directive adding the `transclude` option:

```
app.directive('mainnav', function(){
    return {
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div> <ng-transclude></ng-transclude> <div>',
      controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
          var vm = this;
          vm.autoFocusContent = false;
          vm.status = {
            isFirstOpen: true,
            isFirstDisabled: false
          };

      }]
    }
});
```

After this you can access the parent controller like this:

```
var controller = $element.parent().controller('mainnav');
```

Here is the full example:

https://jsfiddle.net/jm65ajjz/2/

Comment: I minified my code for the example so i will need to make a few adjustments but thank you, I'll have a go